# android studio how to pass and retrieve list item id through intent to other activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Android studio how to pass and retrieve list item id through intent to other activity.
Please put an example for me.
I'm a beginner and it would really help me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: Did you even bother to do a little research?

Answer (score 0):

/// PASSING VALUE

```
Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, CustomClass.class);
                        Bundle b = new Bundle();
                        b.putInt("PASSED_ID", 123);
                        i.putExtras(b);
                        startActivity(i);
```

/// RETREIVING VALUE IN ONCREATE

```
Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
else if (extras != null && extras.containsKey("PASSED_ID")) {
            passedID = extras.getInt("PASSED_ID");
        }
```

Comment: why do i need to yse bundle? like what bundle do?

Comment: @LianLevi seriously, go through the basics of android first.